# populate correct values to the corresponding dynamic headers in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, export-to-csv, json2csv

I am trying to get the results from the database for each month from January and create a csv file for the historic data. I have 3-4 columns as a fixed one and the last column(minutes) should be mapped to each month and append the data to the same csv file. I am not sure how to achieve this in json2csv. Can you please help if you have already came across this scenario?

**username  role Name   activity Name   01-01-2023  01-02-2023  till    01-08-2023** [headers]

user1   role1   act1                              25(**minutes**)           45(**minutes**)

user1   role1   act2                              65(**minutes**)                   150(**minutes**)           1000(**minutes**)

user1   role1   act2                              89                               450

```
let headers = ["username", "role Name", "activity Name"];
    async function generateHeaders() {
    const interval = getIntervalRanges(); // Get the dates from january till previous month
    for (const i of interval.reverse()) {

        const [start, end] = i.split('/');
        const startDate = moment(start);
        const endDate = moment(end);
        const start_date = startDate.utc().add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        const end_date = endDate.utc().subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        headers.push(start_date);
    }

    await main()
   }
    async function main() {
    const interval = getInterval();
    for (const i of interval.reverse()) {

        const [start, end] = i.split('/');
        const startDate = moment(start);
        const endDate = moment(end);
        const start_date = startDate.utc().add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        const end_date = endDate.utc().subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

        const results = await sequelize.query("Query", {
            replacements: {
                start_date: start_date,
                end_date: end_date
            },
            type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        }); // results will have the JSON data for every month from Jan.

        const values = results && results.length && results.map((r) => {
            return {
                userName: r.name,
                roleName: r.role,
                activityName: r.activity,
                minutes: r.minutes

            }
        })

        if (values.length > 0) {
            await createCSVFile(values);
        }
    }

   }
    async function createFile(valuesToWrite) {
    const fileName = output.csv;
    var csvParser = new Parser({
        header: !fs.existsSync(fileName),
        delimiter: ",",
        fields: headers
    });
    var csvData = csvParser.parse(valuesToWrite)

 
    fs.appendFileSync(fileName, csvData + "\n");
    }

    generateHeaders();
```